# Troubleshooting access to a Parallels virtual machine from another computer on the same network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I have PC1 (local IP address `192.168.1.37`) running a CentOS virtual machine with a “bridge mode” Ethernet connection.

TheCentOS virtual machine has an IP on the same network (`192.168.1.33`), Internet connection, and is accessible from PC1 (the host machine) through SSH.

However from PC2 (`192.168.1.43`) I cannot SSH into the CentOS virtual machine at `192.168.1.33`, nor see the webserver. The firewall on PC1 and on virtual machine has been disabled.

`ssh -v` just hangs on “Connecting” and I can't ping it either.

Any idea what is happening or how I can troubleshoot it?

PS: I don’t think it matters, but the virtual machine is running in Parallels on a Mac and I am trying to access it from another Mac.

Comment: not a programming question. check out what fits better: stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: @tobia yes sorry, just too many stackexchange sites opened in my browser, wrong tab....-)

Answer (score 0):

I let the ping go while writing the question.

After some minutes suddenly it started to ping...

It seems that it just takes some time to be recognized. I was able to reproduce it putting the PC1 to sleep an on again.